Does Neoload performance tool supports Java 21 application
We are currently using NeoLoad 6.2 for our load testing purposes. Our application is built on Java 1.8, and NeoLoad 6.2 also includes Java 1.8 by default.
However, our application has now been migrated to Java 21. When we attempt to import GWT/JAR files into NeoLoad, we encounter Java runtime exceptions, as NeoLoad still uses Java 1.8, while our application runs on Java 21.
I have upgraded to the latest NeoLoad version (9.2), but it still includes Java 11. To resolve this, I replaced the inbuilt Java 1.8 version in NeoLoad with the Java 21 files. Unfortunately, after doing so, I am unable to launch NeoLoad.
I would appreciate your assistance with this issue. Thank you in advance.
